# Why do different programs show different contents of c:\windows\system32

Tags: windows

Trying a hack (in Windows 10) that requires a modification in a dll (edit: I'm referring to termsrv.dll) I tried to open the file in my HEX editor (HxD) but couldn't find it in the Open dialog box.

Turns out that browsing to c:\windows\system32 with the Explorer shows me 4321 items. And in the Open dialog of HxD I see only 3029 items.
For the main part the 3029 items are a subset of the 4321. But there are also around 200 files that are only shown in HxD and not in Explorer.

I have UAC on. It makes no difference whether the HxD process is started as an administrator or normally.
As an example, Ultraedit's Open shows the same list as HxD, while Notepad seems to show the list as in Explorer.

Comment: Are to indicate what the file is?  It might have a symbolic link to another location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HxD is a 32 Bit application:

[image]

When you open the system32 folder running on a 64Bit Windows you see the 32 Bit folder `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. And not all dll/exe files are present for both CPU architectures (32 and 64Bit).